# How to factor a polynomial expression in MATHEMATICA?

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I want to factorize the following polynomial in MATHEMATICA:
$1 - 2 r + r^2 - 2 s + 2 r s + s^2 - 2 t + 2 r t + 2 s t - 
 4 r s t + t^2$.

```
1 - 2 r + r^2 - 2 s + 2 r s + s^2 - 2 t + 2 r t + 2 s t - 4 r s t + t^2
```

If done by hand it is easy to see that the above expression can be written in the form of (a+b)(a-b) as:
$(-1 + r + s + t)^2 - (2 \sqrt{r s t})^2$.

I tried using the "Factor" command in MATHEMATICA but it doesn't help, so if there is any command or any code that can help me with the same is appreciated.

Edit: This specific factorization is required as I want the degree of each factored part to be 1. And also if there is any general algorithm so as to obtain factorization for such polynomials in $(a-b)(a+b)$ form so that it can be used with other such polynomials too.

Comment: It's an odd choice of factorization, but `Factor[poly + 4 r s t] - 4 r s t` works. There's also a polynomial in r, `FullSimplify[poly]` giving `r^2 + (-1 + s + t)^2 + 2 r (-1 + s + t - 2 s t)`

Comment: Thanks. Yes that works but what if I have some other polynomial which could be written in the form of (a-b)(a+b), is there a general algorithm for that.( *sorry I have to make that clear in the edit after you gave the solution*)

Comment: If you can write it as (a-b)(a+b) and Factor isn't working as you'd like, then you can always try to solve: `Solve[(a - b) (a + b) == poly, {a, b}]`

Comment: `Solve[1-2 r+r^2-2 s+2 r s+s^2-2 t+2 r t+2 s t-4 r s t+t^2==0,{r}]/.{Rule->Subtract,List->Times}`

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that but it returns just two values of $b$ and doesn't return anything for $a$.

Comment: @chyanog thanks it worked. I tried it with few more examples and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @chyanog This is of course not unique...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you can use in this case

```
ex = 1-2r+r^2-2s+2r s+s^2-2t+2r t+2s t-4r s t+t^2;
(ex/.r s t->u^2//Factor)/.u->Sqrt[r s t]
```

which returns

```
(-1 + r + s + t - 2*Sqrt[r*s*t])*(-1 + r + s + t + 2*Sqrt[r*s*t]
```

I don't think this can be generalized. Any expression with more than one term can be written as $$ a-b = (\sqrt{a})^2 - (\sqrt{b})^2=
(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$$
but the choice of $a$ and $b$ is arbitrary
but also with the proper choice of signs of
the square roots.

Comment: For real `a`, `Sqrt[a^2] == Abs[a]` so the arbitrary `a` and `b` must each be nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

Another way assuming $r\ge 0,s\ge 0,t\ge 0$.

```
expr = 1 - 2 r + r^2 - 2 s + 2 r s + s^2 - 2 t + 2 r t + 2 s t - 4 r s t + t^2;
EXPR = expr /. {s -> S^2 , r -> R^2, t -> T^2} // Factor
EXPR /.{S -> Sqrt[s], R -> Sqrt[r], T -> Sqrt[t]}
```

Comment: I tried that and it worked fine. But I tried to use the similar idea for one more polynomial I had  $r^2 - 2 r s + s^2 - 2 r t - 2 s t + 4 r s t + t^2 $ and the Factor command didn't work. Is there anything special I need to take care of while using this command ?

Comment: Solving tor $t$ we obtain $\left(-2 r s-2 \sqrt{(r-1) r (s-1) s}+r+s-t\right) \left(-2 r s+2 \sqrt{(r-1) r (s-1) s}+r+s-t\right)$